# Prevent duplicate submissions to appended list by hiding option

Tags: jquery, html

I am not sure if this is the best approach in preventing duplicates appended to a list, however, the route I want to take is as follows:

After submitting a selected option from a dropdown list, which is appended to a list, I would then like to hide that option in the dropdown list to prevent the chance of selecting that option again.

Here is the current jQuery is creating that appended list:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var counter = 1;
    var maxAppend = 0;

    $("#addItem").click(function() {
        if (maxAppend >= 10) return;
            var task = $('#searchresults').val();
            var src = $('#searchresults').find(":selected").attr('data-src');

            var $newLi = $("<li><div1><img src='" + src + "'/></div1><div2><input type='text' id='college' name='college' value='" + task + "'/></div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>")
                $newLi.attr("id", "newLi" + counter++);
        maxAppend++;
                $("#tasks").append($newLi);
            });
```

The HTML for the dropdown list:

```
<select id="searchresults">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="1" data-src="blank1.png">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" data-src="blank2.png">Option 2</option>
    <option data-src="blank3.png">Option 3</option>
    <option data-src="blank4.png">Option 4</option>
</select>
                
<input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add" />
```

The HTML for the append list:

```
<div class="items">
    <ul id="tasks">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I found a lot of code on hiding a div upon selection from dropdown list, but not hiding a dropdown list option based on a submitted appended list item.

Comment: you can disable the option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way (add $('#searchresults').find(":selected").remove(); after you append):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var counter = 1;
var maxAppend = 0;

$("#addItem").click(function() {
    if (maxAppend >= 10) return;
        var task = $('#searchresults').val();
        var src = $('#searchresults').find(":selected").attr('data-src');

        var $newLi = $("<li><div1><img src='" + src + "'/></div1><div2><input type='text' id='college' name='college' value='" + task + "'/></div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>")
            $newLi.attr("id", "newLi" + counter++);
            maxAppend++;
            $("#tasks").append($newLi);
            // you also can try .hide() instead remove()
            $('#searchresults').find(":selected").remove();
        });
```

Comment: That was way too easy. Tried .remove previously, but it wiped out my associated image after append. But this seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var counter = 1;
  var maxAppend = 0;

  $("#addItem").click(function() {
    if (maxAppend >= 10) return;
    var task = $('#searchresults').val();
    $("#searchresults option:selected").prop('disabled',true);
    
    var src = $('#searchresults').find(":selected").attr('data-src');

    var $newLi = $("<li><div1><img src='" + src + "'/></div1><div2><input type='text' id='college' name='college' value='" + task + "'/></div2><button class='up'>&#x2191</button><button class='down'>&#x2193</button></li>")
    $newLi.attr("id", "newLi" + counter++);
    maxAppend++;
    $("#tasks").append($newLi);
    //reset dropdown
    $('#searchresults').val('');
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="searchresults">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="1" data-src="blank1.png">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" data-src="blank2.png">Option 2</option>
  <option data-src="blank3.png">Option 3</option>
  <option data-src="blank4.png">Option 4</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="addItem" value="Add" />

<div class="items">
  <ul id="tasks">
  </ul>
</div>
```